# How to dump keychain data of an iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, simulator, dump, keychain

For iOS device, once jailbroken, we can dump the keychain content by using keychain_dumper. I'm curious to know if there are any similar way to dump the iPhone Simulator's keychain data.

I know where the keychain db is located but I'm just not able to decrypt the data. Please help/suggest.

Comment: check https://github.com/ptoomey3/Keychain-Dumper